# C - Seg fault in valid date certificate testing

Tags: c, openssl, x509

I am trying to manually check wether or not a TLS certificatee is valid based on it's date but I am getting a segmentation fault.

I am trying to do this without using X509_cmp_time.

I believe I am on the right track with this (using openssl 1.0.2) but keep getting segmentation faults. Any advice on how to solve this would be much appreciated!

```
time_t *tnow;
int *bday, *bsec, *aday, *asec;
ASN1_TIME anow;
ASN1_TIME *ASN1_TIME_set(ASN1_TIME *anow, time_t tnow);
ASN1_TIME *not_before = X509_get_notBefore(cert);
ASN1_TIME *not_after = X509_get_notAfter(cert);
int nbefore = ASN1_TIME_diff(bday, bsec, not_before, NULL);
int nafter = ASN1_TIME_diff(aday, asec, NULL, not_after);
```

Comment: I'm a muppet - thank you!

Comment: You should not write your own function declarations ; instead include the relevant headers